# Startup disk creator not launching in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, live-usb, startup-disk-creator

After opening the dash and search for Startup Disk Creator.
I have clicked but it's not launching the startup disk creator.
In that case, what should I do? And is there any alternative apps similar to this one.

**Note** I would like to let you inform, I have change some settings on compizconfig-settings-manager. Maybe it has some impact. Whatever, right now how can I launch this app?

[image]

Comment: try running `usb-creator-gtk` from the terminal and see if there is some useful output.

Comment: after writing this on terminal showing me this message "-bash: /usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: so there is no python3 binary in your /usr/bin )) try to install python version 3

Comment: have you solved this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

If you couldn't fix `usb-creator-gtk` you can try to use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/).

Or just use CLI utility [dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)).